# declare arrays in Java as global variable

Tags: java, arrays, int, global-variables

I have retrieved some arrays in Java socket from the client, and i want to declare those arrays as global variables. For example; I would like to declare "Cars" as a global variable so i can use it in other parts of the code too.

```
        while (true)

        {

            int[] data = (int[])ois.readObject();
            oos.close();
            ois.close();

        System.out.println("Cars: " + (data[0]));
        System.out.println("Vans: " + (data[1]));
        break;
        }
        incoming.close();
    }
```

Comment: java doesn't have global variables. You can create a public static variable, or an instance variable that you access through mutators

Comment: @Stultuske How would i do that?

Comment: you are working with sockets, yet you have no idea how to create a static variable or an instance variable?

Comment: *Don't* try to do it with global variables. Return the array from this method, pass the array to the places that need it.

Comment: It seems strange that you are using an advanced feature of Java without having first learned the basics.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about your scenario, but you can declare it as

`public static int[] data;` 
in a class called MyGlobals.java let's say.

And every time yo want to use it you can call `MyGlobals.data`

Example:

```
MyGlobals.data = (int[])ois.readObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a class level variable for array and assign the value returned from client to it. Then you can use that in other methods of your class. Example below

```
public class ClassLevel {
    private static int[] data;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ...
        ...
        data = (int[])ois.readObject();
        ...
        ...

        printArray();
    }

    private static void printArray() {
        for (int i : data) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```